# Optimizing XY Plot Data

Tags: java, android, optimization

I'm currently working on an android application that reads a lot of data from sensors and graphs said data live.

My problem is that there are a extremely large amount of readings. Each dot has an X and Y value.

How should I go about detecting and trimming straight lines with unnecessary dots? 
[image: Before][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any 3 contiguous points that are colinear can lose the middle point.  That should be the core of your algorithm:  traverse all x, and if [x, x+1, x+2] are colinear, drop [x+1] and try again from x.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to detect if the y co-ordinate of successive two point is same.If they are same you can omit the first point.

*For example:* A(3,4),B(4,4),C(6,4),D(7,6)..you can omit B and draw line form A to C and then C to D.

Other way is:
You can detect the slope of the lines.If the slope of the line is same that means they will join to form a straight line.You can omit those lines.